# MathJax config is not taking ## as inline Math delimiter

Tags: javascript, html, mathjax

I am using the latest MathJax library, which is v 3.2.
I have the following code in head part of my webpage. Yet when I use `##` as delimiter for inline Math config, it actually creates a link as shown in screenshot (look at the blue part that says `#x`), If I add a space after the second # as in `## x ##` then it works, but I shouldn't have to do that.

I am missing something here. I tried preceding the delimiters with a backslash in the config JavaScript as in `\#\#` but it didn't work.

**Question:**
What changes I need in my JavaScript below to make the delimiter `##` work for inline math with latest MathJax? Or maybe nothing can be done here since the rich text editor for making this entry is behaving in this manner. In that case, I'll have to add a space after the initial delimiter `##` and there's no way to prevent this problem.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
       window.MathJax = {
          tex: {
            inlineMath: [['##', '##'], ['\\(', '\\)']]
         }
      };
</script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/3.2.0/es5/tex-chtml-full.js"
 integrity="sha512-H1celT3zndvCGQ6MQhHhhbHobnAcJIr0F/hWbLQHOPJNb5psixpjP3KFLfL5MUCGjReje/+DFo+ByaB9OtxmdQ=="
 crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

**UPDATE 1:**
I even tried using html code for the hash character #, but it didn't work. I tried by replacing '##' in above Javascript with `'&num;&num'` and also `'&#35;&#35'` or `'&#x23;&#x23;'`, but none of them worked.

[image: Delimiter Problem in Mathjax for ##]

Comment: Notice that `#x` is shown in blue, apparently indicating a link.  You haven't mentioned what content management system (CMS) you are using, but it looks like it turns text of the form `#xyz` into a link automatically.  That means the content of the page contains `#<a href="#x">#-2=0##`, which doesn't match your delimiters when MathJax looks for them.  That is why the expression is not being found.  If you can't modify that automatic feature of your CMS, you may have to choose different delimiters, or use `## ` (with a space) or `#\#` for the first delimiter.

Comment: I am using this in a Wix website and they have their own proprietary rich text editor for their forums app in which this is happening.